# How to add to an array list through another constructor?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, collections, constructor

So I need to try to add to my qualification arrayList through this constructor in my driver class. I'm taking all my input in through the keyboard using scanner 
I'm a beginner programmer and I think its just something basic.

```
public class Driver {

private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private Doctor doctor;
private Qualification qualifications;
```

```
System.out.println("Enter doctors name: ");
                    sc.nextLine();
                    String name = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter doctors date of birth");
                    String dob = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter doctors gender");
                    String gender = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter doctors address");
                    String address = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter doctors contact number");
                    String contactNumber = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Was the doctor qualified in Ireland?");
                    boolean qualifiedInIreland = sc.nextBoolean();
                    System.out.println("Add doctor qualifications");



Doctor doctor1 = new General(name, dob, gender, address,contactNumber, qualifiedInIreland, <Qualification> qualifications);
                    med1.addDoctor(doctor1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

med1 object is of which type?
Please provide full code

You need to store qualifications in Arraylist , then pass Arraylist of qualification to Doctor constructor.

Try adding this

```
ArrayList<String> qualifications = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("Add doctor qualifications");
while(sc.hasNext){
        qualifications.add(sc.nextLine());  
}
```

and then

```
Doctor doctor1 = new General(name, dob, gender, address,contactNumber, qualifiedInIreland, qualifications);
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. med1 is declared at the beginning. private DoctorAPI med1 = new DoctorAPI();

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify any type parameter, when passing them to the function:

```
Doctor doctor1 = new General(name, dob, gender, address,contactNumber, qualifiedInIreland, qualifications);
```